# on publish feed, facebook 3.0 examples

Tags: android, facebook

so i followed the tutorial pages in the facebook dev site and i have this code:

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.view.Menu;

        public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

        private MainFragment mainFragment;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // Add the fragment on initial activity setup
        mainFragment = new MainFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(android.R.id.content, mainFragment).commit();
    } else {
        // Or set the fragment from restored state info
        mainFragment = (MainFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);
    }
    }

        @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
    }
```

### }

and this is the fragment class

```
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Collection;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.facebook.FacebookRequestError;
    import com.facebook.HttpMethod;
    import com.facebook.Request;
    import com.facebook.RequestAsyncTask;
    import com.facebook.Response;
    import com.facebook.Session;
    import com.facebook.SessionState;
    import com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper;
    import com.facebook.widget.LoginButton;



    public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");
    private static final String PENDING_PUBLISH_KEY = "pendingPublishReauthorization";
    private boolean pendingPublishReauthorization = false;
    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
    private Button shareButton;

        private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
            Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
    };
    protected String TAG;

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null && (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed())) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
    }
    uiHelper.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

        @Override
    public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }

        @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putBoolean(PENDING_PUBLISH_KEY, pendingPublishReauthorization);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  } 

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
    LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
    shareButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.shareButton);
    shareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            publishStory();        
        }
    });
    authButton.setFragment(this);



    return view;
  }

  private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state,Exception exception) {
    if (state.isOpened()) {
        shareButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (pendingPublishReauthorization && 
                state.equals(SessionState.OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED)) {
            pendingPublishReauthorization = false;
            publishStory();
        }

    } else if (state.isClosed()) {
        shareButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}


private void publishStory() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    Log.i(TAG,session.toString());
    if (session != null){

        // Check for publish permissions    
        List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
        if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
            pendingPublishReauthorization = true;
            Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session
                    .NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS);
        session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
            return;
        }

        Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
        postParams.putString("name", "Facebook SDK for Android");
        postParams.putString("caption", "Build great social apps and get more installs.");
        postParams.putString("description", "The Facebook SDK for Android makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated Android apps.");
        postParams.putString("link", "https://developers.facebook.com/android");
        postParams.putString("picture", "https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png");

        Request.Callback callback= new Request.Callback() {
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                JSONObject graphResponse = response
                                           .getGraphObject()
                                           .getInnerJSONObject();
                String postId = null;
                try {
                    postId = graphResponse.getString("id");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.i(TAG,
                        "JSON error "+ e.getMessage());
                }
                FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                if (error != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity()
                         .getApplicationContext(),
                         error.getErrorMessage(),
                         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity()
                             .getApplicationContext(), 
                             postId,
                             Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        };

        Request request = new Request(session, "me/feed", postParams, 
                              HttpMethod.POST, callback);

        RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
        task.execute();
    }

}
private boolean isSubsetOf(Collection<String> subset, Collection<String> superset) {
    for (String string : subset) {
        if (!superset.contains(string)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

### }

so i have all the code its mean to work in this two pages 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/login-with-facebook/
and 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/publish-to-feed/

for some reason i can log in, that is done, but now when i click share it just stays loading forever untill my android device ask me to shut down the application because is frozen, the log cat says facebook.katana is not respoding, so how can i work around this. is something related to permisions in the app dashboard? or what is wrong. i need to know if i did something wrong. before i start again and do it all over again.

Update : after almost 24 hours finally i got the posted message in my wall, so it seems this work after all, but facebook seems unresponsive sometimes.